# Show that in any finite field, there exists a non-trivial solution for $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2 = 0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that in any finite field, there exists a non-trivial solution for $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2 = 0$.

I have shown it for finite fields of cardinality $q$, when $4$ divides $q-1$ and when $q-1$ is odd. In such finite fields, $-1$ has a square root. Hence, $x^2+y^2 = 0$ has a non-trivial solution.

I want a non-trivial solution for the above equation when $q-1 \equiv 2 (\mod 4)$? Here, we already know that there is no non-trivial solution for $x^2+y^2 = 0$.

Is there a more general approach that does not care about the cardinality of the field?

Comment: Apply [Lagrange's four-square theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem) to the characteristic of the field?

Comment: Actually a simple counting argument shows that there are always solutions with $z=1$ and $w=0$. It's been done in this site many times. Search for it.

Comment: Hmm. Couldn't find it. Basically the set of elements of the form $1+y^2$ has $(q+1)/2$ elements. The same holds for the set of elements of the form $-x^2$. There those two sets must intersect non-trivially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jyrki points out, the set of elements of the form $1+y^2$ has $(q+1)/2$ elements where $q$ is the cardinality of the field. Similarly for set of elements of the form $-x^2$. See my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480509/finite-field-satisfies-1-lambda2-alpha-mu2-0/480517#480517) for proofs of these facts.