# Show that for any prime p, there are integers $x, y$ such that $p| x^2+y^2+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity

Show that for any prime p, there are integers $x, y$ such that $p\mid x^2+y^2+1$

Comment: I've shown that. What now? Do you want me to present you the proof or something?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1260928/show-that-for-any-prime-p-there-are-integers-x-and-y-such-that-p/1260948#1260948

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider an odd prime $p$.

Show that the residues of $x^2$ modulo $p$ for $0\le x\le (p-1)/2$ are distinct.

Similarly,the residues of  $-y^2-1$ modulo $p$ for $0\le y\le (p-1)/2$ are distinct. Then apply pigeonhole principle.