# $p|(20a^2+16b^2+2559)$

Tags: number-theory

Show that for a prime $p \geq 7$, there always exist integers $a, b$ such that $p|(20a^2+16b^2+2559)$

I still cannot figure out how to solve this problem.

My thought :

$x^2 \equiv -1(\bmod p) \rightarrow x^4 \equiv 1(\bmod p)$    ---[1]

By Fermat's little theorem, $ x^{p-1} \equiv 1(\bmod p)$   ---[2]

From[1],[2], $4|p-1 \rightarrow p \equiv 1(\bmod 4)$

Comment: **Hint** $ $ Pigeonhole principal, same as in [this classic case.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1260928/242)

Comment: @Bill Dubuque, Thank you for the very helpful link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to show there are $a$, $b$ with
$$20a^2\equiv-16b^2-2559\pmod p.$$
When $p\ge7$, $20a^2$ takes $\frac12(p+1)$ distinct values modulo $p$.
So does $-16b^2-2550$....

Comment: I get it now. Thank you !