# For every prime p there is a sum of squares congruent to -1 mod p

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-residues

> For every prime $p$, there exists $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $p\mid a^2+b^2+1$

For context, this question shows up as a statement on a hint to showing that every positive integer is a sum of 4 squares using the Hurwitz Quaternions, I managed to solve the problem using this fact but I don't see why this fact holds at all, specifically I managed to solve it for $p=2$ or $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$ in a trivial manner, but for the other primes I don't quite see how that would work, I assume it can be solved using some results from quadractic residues but I am not sure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that for any prime $ p $, there are integers $ x $ and $ y $ such that $ p|(x^{2} + y^{2} + 1) $.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1260928/show-that-for-any-prime-p-there-are-integers-x-and-y-such-that-p) . Found using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24p%20%5Cmid%20a%5E2%20%2B%20b%5E2%20%2B%201%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aprime&p=1). There's also [Quadratic Congruence for every prime](/q/693353) here, plus the AoPS thread [For every prime number](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1548601p9405454).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is well known that there are exactly $\frac{p+1}{2}$ quadratic residues modulo $p$ (including $0$) for any odd prime $p$. Therefore, $a^2$ can take $\frac{p+1}{2}$ distinct values modulo $p.$ The same holds for $-b^2 - 1.$ Now, we have $p+1$ values modulo $p$ in total. By the pigeonhole principle, there is at least one pair of these values which are congruent. This observation concludes the proof.

Comment: And in the same way, for *every* $c \bmod p$ there are $a$ and $b$ such that $a^2 + b^2 \equiv c \bmod p$.