# elements in Field such that $1+\alpha a^2+\beta b^2=0$

Tags: ring-theory, finite-fields

If $F$ is a finite filed, $\alpha, \beta$ are two non-zero elements of $F$. Then Show that there exists elements $a,b$ in $F$ such that $1+\alpha a^2+\beta b^2=0$.

I don't have any clue on how to approach this.
Please help me with this problem.

Comment: I am not an expert on this topic, but this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480509/finite-field-satisfies-1-lambda2-alpha-mu2-0 looks similar to me.

Answer (score 2):

The equation is equivalent to
$$1+\alpha a^2=-\beta b^2.$$
If more than half the elements in the finite field $F$ are squares, then
$1+\alpha a^2$ takes more than half the values in $F$ and
$-\beta b^2$ takes more than half the values in $F$. So there has
to be a collision: some value of
$1+\alpha a^2$
must equal some value of $-\beta b^2$.

If $F$ has even order, every element of $F$ is a square.

If $F$ has odd order, it has $\frac12(1+|F|)$ squares.